# Approximate 5y swap rate move in 1 tick move in 5y treasury

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rate-swap, treasuries

If CT5s (the current on the run 5y treasury) goes from 99-20 to 99-21 - what will be the approx rate move in the 5y swap rate.  Just trying to ascertain rule of thumbs for 5y, 10y and 30y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be assuming swap spreads are constant, but a 1tick change in the 5y otr, is approximately -0.7bps on the swap